# How to make Show Notification Mantine clickable?

Tags: next.js, frontend, mantine

hello I'm using this notification function from mantine for my nextjs webiste

notifications.show({
title: 'Default notification',
message: 'Hey there, your code is awesome! ',
})

I want to it to be clickable, as I tried to add these props to make it clickable:
notifications.show({
href:"/"
Link:"/"
title: 'Default notification',
message: 'Hey there, your code is awesome! ',
})

https://mantine.dev/x/notifications/

It doesn't work please help .